# Apache Server Alias When Folder Does Not Exists

Tags: apache

Is there any way to alias to a folder that might not exists sometimes? For example a folder in an external HDD?

Comment: Certainly, I don't see any issue with that. Obviously you will get an http error returned (either 500 or 404), but apart from that things should work. The only thing you have to take care of is that the folder exists when you _start_ the http server.

Comment: To stay in control over the http error returned whilst the folder is _not_ available you can use the rewriting module: implement a condition that checks if the physical file exists (`RewriteCond ... -f`) and simply redirects to an error handler otherwise. That way you can even return a custom error page if you like.

Comment: @arkascha "The only thing you have to take care of is that the folder exists when you start the http server." This is exactly the problem.

Comment: Why should that be a problem? Just create the folder hierarchy up to where the `Alias` points to whilst that drive is _not_ connected. That file tree will be hidden the moment the hdd is mounted into the file system. So the folder _always_ exists, only its content changes. You can even place some static index or error document in that "shadow folder".

Comment: @arkascha I'm using windows. What do you mean then. I don't have the drive when HDD is not connected. So what do I have to point to?

Comment: You operate an http server on an MS-Windows base? I mean sure, that is possible from a technical point of view. But... _why_? Apart from that - no, indeed then things won't work. The file system tree is handled _very_ strange on those systems. I never understood _why_ the implemented all those exceptions and specific situations for something as easy as a file tree.

Comment: @arkascha It's just personal interest.

Comment: What difference does that make?